# How do I capture the audio of a wpf window or cscore output in c#?

Tags: wpf, audio, live-streaming, audio-player, cscore

I made a music player in wpf using [cscore](https://github.com/filoe/cscore). Now, I want to add a feature so I can stream the output in real-time (like a radio) to another instance of the music player over internet. I could see how to stream the data later, but first I need to know how to get the bytes of the audio output. I'm asking for help because I'm lost, I've done some research and found nothing but how to stream the desktop audio. That's not a solution, because I want to listen to the same music with some friends while hanging out on Discord, so if I stream the desktop audio, they will listen to themselves besides the music. Any help will be welcome. Thanks in advance!

Comment: kleylux I'm also working on a music player based on CSCore. Check it out [here](https://github.com/itsAbhi650/YAMP-alpha) when you have time. Would love to have any suggestions or valuable inputs. And hey you gave me a new  feature idea! If you get it working let me know! ;)

Comment: I've checked it out, great work! I like its features, and it's easy to use. There were some bugs that I had to fix to get it to work but I think you already know about them. I would recommend you to optimize its RAM consumption since in my machine it uses 1GB (with 887 songs), and that's a lot IMO. One thing I can recommend to lower the RAM comsumption is to load images only when you need them.

Comment: kleylux whoa that is such a benchmark.. being honest I'm just a beginner and currently trying to master basics. That lazy loading tip is great. I'll surely work on that! oh and hey mind sharing your github url?

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't upload my source code to github. I've created a repo but I'm using it as an updates provider. I also have a website but it's under maintenance. But you can download it from this [google drive link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Eqb0rd27cc0XmGVrs2c6LWnDGxFPQfZW/view?usp=sharing), if you want to take a look and tell me what you think about it ;)

Comment: As it is under development, there are a lot of things in mind to add. But it's usable. If you have any problem when executing it please tell me, because it uses a speech synthesizer and I don't know why sometimes it won't run if you don't have some specific voices installed in your windows. For more info about the music player you can check out this outdated but functional [website](https://vaimp.000webhostapp.com/en/index.html).

Comment: Hey I saw your player! its actually nice and there are lot of things I'm seeing that I'll Implement in my player too. Its a nice player..

Comment: Thank you and good luck! And Just for curiosity, what features did you try? Because there are a lot of features that might be hidden or nonintuitive, like the Relax Mode (fullscreen visualizer)

Comment: He lets carry on [here](https://gitter.im/CSCorePlayers/community), as it's against rules to drag comment with chats unrelated to questions.

Comment: oh kk sorry, i didn't know about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am have not used cscore I mainly use naudio a similar library that facilitates getting audio to and from the sound card. So I will try and answer in a way that allows you to find what you are looking for in cscore.

In your player code you will be pulling data from the audio file. In naudio this is done with a audio file reader. I think it is called a wavFileReader in cscore, This file reader translates the audio file into a stream of audio samples in the form of byte arrays, the byte arrays are then used to feed the WASAPI Out to allow the audio to play on the sound card.

The ideal place to start with your streaming system would be in the middle of those two processes. So rather than just passing the audio samples to the sound card you need to take a copy of the byte array containing the samples. it is this data you will need to stream to your friends.

From here you will need to look at compressing the audio and streaming protocols like RTP all can be done in c#. The issue will be, as it always is in audio having your data stream keep pace with the sound card. Every time WASAPIOut asks for more samples you need to have the ready otherwise the audio will be choppy.

I do hope this helps point you in the right direction. Others with experience with cscore may have some code examples to assist you more directly I am simply trying to point you in the right direction

Comment: Thank you Max, I really appreciate it. I'm gonna go deeper into what you said. I might have to rewrite the code a little bit, but let's see if I can do it.

Comment: After some good research, I finally learned how to get samples from CSCore. I've been testing it and I could get it to work (getting buffer from an `IWaveSource` and writing it to a `WritableBufferingSource`). Now I have to deal with Networking :P. Well, I want to thank you for pointing me in the right direction!